# Radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(2^{-n}+4^{-n}) z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm trying to find for what values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ the series $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(2^{-n}+4^{-n})z^n$$ converges. My main methods are the nth root test and the ratio test. I believe it can be done using these. However I am unsure due to the negative infinity in the series, I'm not sure how I can apply either of the two tests to this series.

My initial thought was to split this up into two series:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(2^{-n}+4^{-n})z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2^{-n}+4^{-n})z^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^{n}+4^{n})z^{-n}$$ however I'm not sure if that is useful or indeed allowed. Then using the ratio test I achieve that the radius of convergence for the first sum is $1$, i.e., convergent for $|z|<1$ and divergent for $|z|>1$ and undetermined for $|z|=1$. However I do not know how to go about the other limit with the exponent of the $z$ being $-n$. Can anyone advise on a method which can allow one to use the tests on these type of series?

Comment: Just substitute $1/z=w$, now run your convergence tests and lastly substitute back to get the restriction on $z$

Comment: If $(2^{-n}+4^{-n})|z|^n\to0$ when $n\to+\infty$ then $|z|<2$. If $(2^{-n}+4^{-n})|z|^n\to0$ when $n\to-\infty$ then $|z|>4$. Thus the series $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(2^{-n}+4^{-n})z^n$ diverges for every $z$.

Comment: the first one is convergent for $|z| <2 $. for the other series, the convergence is inverted : converging for $|z| >4 $ and divergent for $|z| < 4$.

Comment: By the way, the term "radius of convergence" is incorrect for series $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_nz^n$.